# Unterschied zwischen Ding und Sache

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, usage

Täuscht mich mein subjektives Sprachgefühl oder klingt in den folgenden beiden Satzpaaren der jeweils erste Satz *objektiv* "natürlicher" und "richtiger" als der zweite?

- **"Er erklärte ihm verschiedene Dinge, nämlich ..."**
- "Er erklärte ihm verschiedene Sachen, nämlich ..."
- **"Er erklärte ihm eine Sache, nämlich ..."**
- "Er erklärte ihm ein Ding, nämlich ..."

Lässt sich zu solchen Feinheiten des Sprachgebrauchs etwas Sinnvolles sagen? Gibt es einen nachvollziehbaren Grund für den feinen Unterschied zwischen "Ding" und "Sache", der sich darin äußert, dass man das eine Wort in obigem Kontext eher im Singular und das andere eher im Plural verwendet?

Answer (score 1):

Nun, ein Ding ist - etwas mehr als eine Sache - etwas Physisches, Anfassbares - Eben etwas *Dingliches*. Eine *Sache* kann durchaus ein Vorgang (z.B. eine *Strafsache*) oder ein Sachverhalt sein. Nur in der Standardsprache wird "Ding" auch manchmal in diesem Kontext verwendet, wie in

> "Danke, dass du mir geholfen hast!" - "Kein Ding"

Da man normalerweise eher Sachverhalte und Zusammenhänge *erklärt* als physische Dinge, klingen eigentlich alle deine Beispielsätze erst einmal ungewöhnlich. Einen Unterschied zwischen deinen Beispielen kann ich nicht ausmachen. Auch dein Gefühl, dass eher Plural als Singular "passt", kann ich nicht nachvollziehen.